# MySQL - Does table_name exist based off list of table_name

Tags: mysql

I hope my description is accurate. What I'm attempting to find is whether or not a table_name exists based off a list created by another table.

For instance. Table A has a list of children tables

```
a_zcmdb_middleware_mq_view
a_zcmdb_middleware_tomcat_view
a_zcmdb_middleware_tomcat_web_view
a_zcmdb_middleware_websphere_view
a_zcmdb_myapp_app_db_view
a_zcmdb_myapp_fprint_dq_view
a_zcmdb_myapp_host_ear_war_view
a_zcmdb_oracle_catalog
a_zcmdb_oracle_instance
a_zcmdb_oracle_physical
a_zcmdb_oracle_rel_catlog
a_zcmdb_oracle_rel_instance
a_zcmdb_physical_db
a_zcmdb_software_product
```

I would like to check the database to make sure these tables actually exist.

I spot checked a few and found this table to be non-existent.

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'a_zcmdb_middleware_tomcat_web_view' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested SELECT in the `IN` clause to fetch your results from the `information_schema` and based on what this query results, you can obtain the existing tables:

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'your_db' 
  AND table_name IN (SELECT your_db.test.tb_name FROM your_db.test)
```

Comment: Thank you. I never thought of using information_schema this way. I will give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

The [`TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) table in the built-in [`information_schema`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) database has the info you're looking for.

```
SELECT * from information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'a_zcmdb_middleware_tomcat_web_view';
```

Comment: This only addresses one table.

Comment: The query is just illustrative. Extending the functionality to all your tables should be trivial and is left as an exercise for the reader.